# Can't remote into Mac mini

Tags: mac, macos, remote-desktop

I have a MacBook Pro and a Mac mini, both running Mountain Lion. This problem, however, started when I had Lion. I can remote in to my MacBook Pro just fine from my iPhone and iPad. But I can't remote into my Mac mini. It started out just fine and I could remote into the Mac mini from my iPhone, iPad as well as my MacBook Pro. Later (I was still on Lion), I could still log in from my iDevices but no longer could from my MacBook Pro. This behavior continued after installing Mountain Lion. Now, I can't remote in from anywhere. I want to avoid doing a clean install, but I will I have to.

I have tried switching from Remote Management under Sharing to Screen Sharing, and back. nothing works. Recently (before I lost the ability to remote in at all, but after I lost the ability to remote in from my MacBook), I also lost the ability to edit my parental controls on the Mac mini from my MacBook. Little by little, I am completely losing the ability to remote in/screen share to my Mac mini at all. Currently, I can only remote in via SSH for a terminal.

My network includes my AirPort Extreme, Time Capsule, MacBook Pro (mid-2010), Mac mini (mid 2010), iPad (3), iPhone 4S, and my father's PC. Only my father's PC is connected by wire. The rest is wireless.

If anyone can guide me in the right direction, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Some more info would be helpful here. What app are you using on your iOS devices and Mac to connect to your Mini? What happens when you try to connect—do any errors appear, or does nothing appear to happen?

First off, make sure **Screen Sharing** is enabled in Sharing Preferences (Remote Management is only for using [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/), so don't bother with that unless you're actually using that program). Double-check that *Allow access* is set to either "All Users", or "Only these users" with your user name included in the box.

Now try connecting from another Mac, using the Finder's **Connect to Server** dialog (under the **Go** menu, or ⌘K). Under *Server Address*, type in `vnc://IP_OF_YOUR_MINI` then hit connect. If you can connect that way, but not using the Finder's Shared panel, then the problem is likely in the Bonjour service that advertises the screen sharing option.

Another thing to check is what version of Apple Remote Desktop Client you have installed. If you have 3.6, [there's a bug that can cause timeouts for Screen Sharing/VNC clients](http://help.edovia.com/kb/screens/connection-timeout-while-authenticating). The temporary fix is removing `/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement` and re-installing [3.5.3](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1532). This worked for me on Lion, I don't know if it will work on Mountain Lion. **Make sure to keep a backup copy of the files you delete, in case the install doesn't work.**

Comment: Sorry about that. I did get in a bit of a rush, didn't I? On my iDevices, I use [Remoter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remoter-vnc-remote-desktop/id369626098?mt=8). It's worked great, plus I can remote in to my dad's PC using RDP if he needs help.

When I try to connect through Remoter, it does nothing other than show the message "Connecting..." and it just sits there with no errors. When I try to connect with the Mac, I get "Connection failed to 'Mac mini'." after a few minutes.

Thanks for the tip on Remote Management. But I've had no luck with Screen Sharing, either.

I'm

Comment: I'm working on the Mac mini with you other suggestions now and I'll report back when I finish.

Comment: Ok, I was running 3.6, and I rolled back to 3.5.3, but I still can't connect. I set the Mac mini back to Screen Sharing instead of Remote Management and tried to connect through Connect to Server. Nothing is working.

Comment: Try enabling the *VNC viewers may control screen with password* setting (click the Computer Settings… button under Screen Sharing).

Comment: Did that. Still nothing. It's looking like maybe a clean install. Thanks so much for the help. Any other ideas? I'm willing to try anything to avoid a clean install.

Comment: When I first tried the Remote Desktop Client fix it didn't seem to work at first, so I tried to make sure I cleaned everything involving ARD. In the terminal using `mdfind` I searched for everything involving ARDAgent, RemoteDesktop and RemoteManagement and trashed them. Then I reinstalled the ARD Client v3.5.3 and it seemed to stick.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll try that shortly. Sorry for the delay. Schoolwork meant that the Mac mini had to take a back seat. I'll hopefully get to that as soon as school is over today. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: "Me, too."  Just updated my MBP from SnowLeopard to Mt.Lion, trying to "share screen" from Lion on iMac.  All of this worked 5 minutes prior to install (in fact, I kicked off the installation remotely! :) Settings all look right; I toggled to ARD and back to screen-share.  I rebooted.  I "disconnected" (from remote.)  I Connect As...-ed (the allowed user name), etc.  No joy  :\